# Listing Windows services info in Listview

Tags: asp.net

I want to Populate Windows Services information in Listview using c# in a webform.

I worked on Grideview, where we bind the data source(returned as datatable from DB) with the gridview directly.

I tried similar approach using Listview, where I wanted to return the list of services and bind to Listview.

```
protected ListView GetServices()
        {
           try
            {
                ListView lstServices = new ListView();

                ServiceController[] svcs = ServiceController.GetServices();

                foreach (ServiceController svc in svcs)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.Text = svc.DisplayName;
                    item.SubItems.Add(svc.ServiceName);
                    item.SubItems.Add(svc.Status.ToString());

                    lstServices.Items.Add(item);
                }
                return lstServices;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: how you call this method and how you add this list view to page?

Comment: My idea is, on a Submit button ONClick event, function should return the Listview items (service details) and bind it with the Listview.

Comment: Is there any purpose to return as a ListView?. Rather using ListView you can use datatable or dataset then you can bind it ListViewControl.  Like   listView.DataSource = LoadDataSet() OR LoadDataTable();
            listView.DataBind();